# How to load urls in the webview of second activity on button clicks

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

i have two button on my first activity say A and i have a webview in my second activity say B
now i want to load urls in webview on button click event.if i click on btn1 button then webview should show the google.com website , and if i click on the btn2 button then webview should show the gmail.com website,  here is my code for activity of A and B . thanks in advance

**code for activity A**

```
 Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_google);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent (google.this,webview.class);
                     google.this.startActivity(intent);

               }
                }

                    );

             Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gmail);
             btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent (google.this,webview.class);
                    google.this.startActivity(intent);

               }
                }


                );
```

**here is the code of activity B**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.webview );

           WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient()
           {
               // Override page so it's load on my view only
               @Override
               public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
               {
                // This line we let me load only pages inside Firstdroid Webpage
                 view.loadUrl(url);
                   // Load new URL Don't override URL Link

                // Return true to override url loading (In this case do nothing).
                return true;
               }
           };


           // Get Web view
           mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.mywebview ); //This is the id you gave 
           mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
           mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);       //Zoom Control on web (You don't need this 
                                                  //if ROM supports Multi-Touch      
           mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //Enable Multitouch if supported by ROM
           mWebView.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
           mWebView.reload();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this for btn1

```
 Intent intent = new Intent (google.this,webview.class);
intent.putExtra("google.com", "http://www.google.com");
                     google.this.startActivity(intent);
```

You have to do this for btn2

```
 Intent intent = new Intent (google.this,webview.class);
intent.putExtra("gmail.com", "http://www.gmail.com");
                     google.this.startActivity(intent);
```

In activity2

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null){
String googleUrl = extras.getString("google.com");
String gmailUrl = extras.getString("gmail.com");
if (googleUrl != null)
    mWebView.loadUrl(googleUrl);
else if (gmailUrl != null)
 mWebView.loadUrl(gmailUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont clearly understood your question, but to load url anywhere from webview do this:

```
mwebview.loadUrl(YOUR_URL);
```

And if you want to pass url from A activity to B activity use

```
intent.putExtra(KEY,VALUE)
```

Hope This Helps

Comment: thanks quick reply , suppose i have two buttons as i mentioned above .now i want when i click on btn1 then webview should load google webpage like mwebview.loadurl("google.com") and when i click on btn2 then mwebview should load gmail webpage in same webview like mwebview.loadurl("gmail.com") but on activity B. activity B has a xml file where i declared the mwebview